# forceScheme('https') breaks laravel backpack filters

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have the following code in my AppServiceProvider boot method, which is supposed to force HTTPS. Unfortunately, this is causing Laravel Backpack filters to not function properly.

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

However, if I pull my git repo locally, the filters function properly with this piece of code in place.

Any ideas into the cause of the issue, or where to poke around in, are much appreciated.